# How to recursively parse a single Json field that is defined multiple times, in Play Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

Take the following JSON string as an example:

```
val document = """{
    "id": "12345",
    "createdTime": "13332517",
    "data": {
        "status": "active",
        "createdTime": "13345178"
    }"""
```

The field `createdTime` is defined twice in the document.
To return the `createdTime` at the top layer is done by:

```
val createdTime = Json.parse(document \ "createdTime")
```

Take the following JSON string; it is the same as the first example, but it is now an array:

```
val document1 = """[{
    "id": "12345",
    "createdTime": "13332517",
    "data": {
        "status": "active",
        "createdTime": "13345178"
    }
}, {
    "id": "67890",
    "createdTime": "13332565",
    "data": {
        "status": "active",
        "createdTime": "13345173"
    }
}]"""
```

To recursively return "createdTime" is defined as:

```
val createdTime1 = Json.parse(document1) \\ "createdTime"
```

However this also returns the nested `createdTime` fields. Is there a way to recursively return only the top layer `createdTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse the `document1` and cast it to `JsArray`, you should have an array. Then you can iterate on the value with `map` to get the top layer createdTime's.

`val createdTimes = Json.parse(document1).as[JsArray].value.map(_ \ "createdTime")`